# Game: ScoreNumber does not increase by 1. It increases by 4 every time (sometimes, 10)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a game where you bounce on platforms.  I want the score to increase by 1 every time you bounce on a platform.  However, it keeps increasing by some random number every time (like 10).

In Game.h I have:

```
int ScoreNumber;
IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreLabel;
-(void)Score;

...
```

In Game.m I have:

```
-(void)Score {
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber +1.0;
    ScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
}

-(void)PlatformMoving {
   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Bird.frame, Platform1.frame)) {
       [self Score];
   }
}
...
```

This should count by 1 every time but it counts by more than 1

Answer (score 3):

If you place a breakpoint in your (void)Score method you'll probably see that its being called multiple times per bounce because the rectangles probably overlap for multiple frames. You could place a check inside the (void)PlatformMoving method to see if the last test failed before calling Score again. This would ensure that Score is never called on 2 consecutive frames and should prevent scoring any more than one point per bounce.

Comment: My guess is that the root cause lies somewhere in the collision detection. After verifying that the method is indeed called multiple times I would check there.

Comment: That is definitely the issue but how do you place a check inside the (void)PlatformMoving method?

Comment: place a boolean in your Game class that holds the last result of your collision test. In your PlatformMoving method check and update this field as neccessary to prevent Score from being called more than once per collision. This will make it so that Score is only called on frames that are the first frame for a given collision.